# How to get a specific video time and then use it to trigger a event

Tags: javascript, html, aframe

I would like to trigger an event/animation after a specific video time or video frame.
for example, a video play to 30 seconds, text will appear.

tried `currentTime`,
tried `loadeddata`
and tried `setTimeout`... but I just don't know the exact API i am looking for.

If someone could give me a hint of keyword what I should search for. I think I will be able to figure out the rest. thankyou

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `timeupdate` event attached to the video element if the `currentTime` is 30, make your event call.

Within the call we can test to see if the time has elapsed using `video.currentTime` which returns the time in seconds the video is currently at.

```js
let video = document.querySelector('video')

// Times in seconds.
const timeframes = [
  {time: 30, triggered: false},
  {time: 60, triggered: false},
  {time: 90, triggered: false}
]

// Watch for currentTime changes
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
  // Find the time to be triggered
  let time = timeframes.find(i => i.time == Math.floor(video.currentTime) && !i.triggered)
  if (time) {
    // A time was found that hasn't been triggered
    time.triggered = true
    // Send the event to the window
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('VideoTimelapse', {detail: time}))
  }
})

// Listen for the event
window.addEventListener('VideoTimelapse', (e) => {
  console.log(`${e.detail.time} seconds have passed`)
})

// The user moved the slider, reset the 'triggered' property back to false
video.addEventListener('seeked', () => timeframes.forEach(i => {i.triggered = false}))
```

```html
<video controls autoplay>
  <source src="https://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Would this be hard locked to the videos FPS?

Comment: This doesn't care what the video FPS is, as it is based on the current time of the video.

Answer (score 1):

YES `timeUpdate` is what exactly I am looking for;
and then I simplify your example to something like this:

```
yourVideo.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    //currentTime use second, if you want min *60
if(yourVideo.currentTime >= 5) {
        yourVideo.pause();
    }
});
```